# Unity 3D Build faild

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I tried to build my 3D game for **Windows** I had this error:

```
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <17b72532ee2c4da1b6f632d3f1705fe0>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

In other forums I saw that they builded for android but I building for PC.I have just setted up networking and then I got this error.Before there was't any problems why building. And I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

When building to pc, try to change the folder you're building to, or create a new one.